# Finding value of an angle in a triangle.

Tags: geometry, triangles

I'm solving some practice problems to prepare for a competitive exam. Here is one which I'm trying to do for some time but still haven't found a solution to:

"In the given figure, $∠ABC = 2∠ACB$ and $AB = DC$. Also, $AD$ is the bisector of $∠BAC$.  Find $∠ABC$."

Here is the drawing I made :
[image: Figure]

Note that I want to find the numerical value of $∠ABC$ in degrees.
Since $AB$ and $DC$ are sides of different triangle, I don't know how to begin.
Also since none of the angles is known, how can I find the value of angle?
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

let angles *=y and o=x, AE=DE so base angles are equal. and by CPCT angle EDC will be 2y. So from triangle ADC y+y+2y+x=180 and from triangle ABC x+x+y+y+x=180, solving these x=36 and hence 2x=72 degrees

Comment: Hi @SanjayJain. Welcome! Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in future :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $BE$ be the bisector of $\angle ABC$ and connect $E$ with $D$. In triangles $ABE$ and $DCE$ we have $\angle ABE = \angle DCE$, $AB=DC$ and $BE=CE$. Hence $AE=ED$.